# How many libraries is too much before there is a performance issue?

Tags: hooks, theming

We are using [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) module to allow for selecting of up to 15 different `Paragraph Types`. As part of this, each one requires its own `CSS` and `JS` since they are vastly different. We already have a common set of `CSS` and `JS` that can be shared (`25%` overall), but there is a large percentage (`75%`) that is unique to each `Paragraph Type`.

We were able to combine lots of the `CSS` and `JS`, which resulted in the creation of `10` libraries and `1` general library to help with the management of these `types`. We are concerned that if we add more `Paragraph Types` the number of libraries could increase to anywhere between `20-30` as newer `Paragraph Types` are needed.

**How many libraries is too much for a custom subtheme before it cause a performance issue (if any)?**

Since there is no extra preprocessing needed per `Paragraph Type`, we simply add them using the `{{ attach_library('mytheme/name') }}` in `twig templates`. The only `hook` that is used is the one to add the `general` library.

`mytheme` is a subtheme and is set as `default and enabled`

Examples:

`paragraph--carousel.html.twig`

```
{# this is the paragraph type specific library #}
{{ attach_library('mytheme/carousel') }} 

<div class="carousel__wrapper"> 
  <div class="carousel__title"> {{ content.field_title }} </div>
  <div class="carousel__subtitle"> {{ content.field_sub_title }} </div>
  <div class="carousel__text"> {{ content.field_description }} </div>
  <div class="carousel__image"> {{ content.field_image }} </div>
  <div class="carousel__dots"> </div>
</div>
```

`paragraph--jump-menu.html.twig`

```
{# this is the paragraph type specific library #}
{{ attach_library('mytheme/jump-menu') }} 

<div class="jmenu__wrapper"> 
  <div class="jmenu__tab"> {{ content.field_title }} </div>
</div>
```

`mytheme.module`

```
function mytheme_preprocess_paragraph(&$variables) {
  // Add general library for paragraphs.
  $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'mytheme/global';
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You need as many as you need. My only suggestion would be to consolidate into as few CSS files as possible. If you have a solid global structure, then the remaining CSS would be small in filesize overall.

Comment: @Kevin I modified the question to be a little more clear. We were worried this may eventually lead to a `performance` issue if we had too many libraries that `Drupal` has to process.

Comment: Hum, this doesn't actually sound like a real problem in my opinion. I mean, do you experience any performance issues? Or have you tried like attaching 1 mio dummy libraries? What happened then? What's your server setup?

Comment: Well these libraries only get loaded if the template file loads, so nothing to worry about. I'm sure Drupal Core has a lots of libraries.

Comment: @NoSssweat right, so even a lot of `paragraph items` are added to the page, we should still be okay because not all of them will be loaded?

Comment: @leymannx We don't see any performance issue yet, but feared it would eventually lead to one if we didn't take any steps now.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil. ;)

Comment: And: Fear is a bad advisor. ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal, the best way to do your CSS is to keep it componentalized, and attach the CSS using #attached directly to the item to which it belongs. This way, the CSS is only ever attached when needed, and if a user overrides the render array further down the pipeline, removing the element to which the assets are attached, the assets will not be attached to the page, including unnecessary CSS.

Then you turn on CSS aggregation (or even better, use the ADVAGG module), and Drupal will handle the heavy lifting, aggregating the files as needed for the page.

So the answer to your question is that there aren't too many libraries. What is more important is effective management of the CSS/JS you are attaching.

Comment: the [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 theme](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-theme), states that the process to which to add `CSS` and `JS` is called a `library` as indicated under `The Process`, `Define a "library", which registers these CSS/JS files with your theme.`

Comment: Ahh I see. Sorry I’ve been working with composer too much recently. I’ll edit my post, but the rest of what I said still stands.

Comment: using the `#attached` array to add the library assumes I print the default `{{ attributes }}`  in my `twig` template for the `paragraph` type. However if you look at my example, this is not the case here.

Comment: The organization is the key point.

Comment: I have two concerns with adding the library in a template. My first concern is that it won't aggregate correctly, though I suspect that my concern may be unfounded, seeing as the function to add the library exists in the first place. My second concern is more an architectural concern. Templates are for output of content, and should only have the output, and simple logic output from the template. Libraries are not part of the output of the template, and therefore I feel they should be added through hooks using the #attached property. Doing it this way covers my first concern as well.

Comment: do you have a way to replicate your first concern? The background behind the `attach_library` may be traced back to [issues #2398331](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2398331). When we have complex conditions to load a `library` we use the `hook_preprocess_hook()`, but in simple conditions we use `attach_library`. When setting the weight, it is important to keep in mind [CSS file organization (for Drupal 8)](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/css/css-file-organization-for-drupal-8). This has allowed for proper aggregation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88115/discussion-between-jaypan-and-usernameabc).